# What does Mimenu mean in Bereishis 3:22

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, parashat-bereishit

Bereishis 3:22 writes: וַיֹּאמֶר יְהוָה אֱלֹהִים, הֵן הָאָדָם הָיָה **כְּאַחַד מִמֶּנּוּ**, לָדַעַת, טוֹב וָרָע; וְעַתָּה פֶּן-יִשְׁלַח יָדוֹ, וְלָקַח גַּם מֵעֵץ הַחַיִּים, וְאָכַל, וָחַי לְעֹלָם

The bolded words make it seem like Hashem is referring to multiple people/beings for man is now "one of us". Who is this group Hashem refers to?

Comment: Perhaps the angels?

Comment: That may be, but I'm looking for sources. If you have a source for that, perhaps post an answer?

Answer (score 5):

[Rashi there](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.3.22.1) says:

> ‏"היה כאחד ממנו" - הרי הוא יחיד בתחתונים כמו שאני יחיד בעליונים ומה היא יחידתו לדעת טוב ורע מה שאין כן בבהמה וחיה

Hashem is comparing Himself to Adam - just like He is unique among the heavenly beings (angels) in His superior knowledge/understanding, so too is man unique among the Earthlings (animals).

[Radak](http://www.sefaria.org/Radak_on_Genesis.3.22.1) compares it to 1:26, where it says בצלמינו כדמותינו. The commentators there all say that He is talking with the angels; this is what Radak says here as well.

> ויאמר ה' אלהים וגו' כאחד ממנו, שיתף עצמו יתברך עם המלאכים כמו שאמר בצלמינו כדמותינו.

Comment: Saadia Gaon says also that the "mimenu" means "from them" not from the heavenly host but from the creations on earth in his knowledge of good and evil.

Comment: *I* wanted to make the comparison to בצלמינו כדמותינו :P